# Trigger PLC multiple times with delays

Tags: plc

I am brand new to PLC's (don't even have a single device in use yet), but I have been programming for more than 20 years and haven taken classes in electrical controls, so I understand machine logic very well.

I am planning an application where a machine will make a simple movement with a preset delay after being triggered.  Specifically, there are many items on a conveyor belt and some of them will be diverted off the belt.  The sensor that triggers this is near the beginning of the belt, and the device to remove them is at the other end.  There will likely be multiple triggers/inputs occurring prior to the end of the previous delayed output.

Is this something most PLC's will readily handle and is there anything special I would need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally we use a shift register to track parts through a machine. This works well for discrete moves but is more problematic for continuous motion such as on a conveyor.

If, for example, your product is 200 mm long then I would index the shift register every 50 mm or so and that way you're guaranteed that each product will be seen at least once and tracked in the shift register. The number of stages required will be the distance between sensors divided by the step. So, for a 1500 mm conveyor you would need 1500 / 50 = 30 stages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbsZyT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Pseudo ladder logic code for a 30-bit shift register.*

In the pseudo code above a 30-bit shift register has been set up starting at F200 (F for 'flag'). If the photoeye is on during a rising edge of the CLK then a '1' is loaded into the shift register at F200 after the existing data has been moved up one position. Any time a '1' reaches F229 the ejector output will turn on.

The 50 mm pulse would ideally be triggered by sensing the rotation of a shaft on the conveyor but if the speed does not change it could be done on a timer.

---

From the comments:

> The important part of the question is the concern that there will be several items on the conveyor at a time in between the sensor and the ejector, will the logic still work as is?

Yes.

```
         | sensor                                           | ejector
     _______         ________        ________        ________
    |_______|       |________|      |________|      |________|   >>>     
 ___________________________________________________________
(___________________________________________________________)
                        Conveyor

         1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1    0 mm
         1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1   50 mm
         1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1  100 mm
```

*Figure 2. Shift register contents.*

Comment: The important part of the question is the concern that there will be several items on the conveyor at a time in between the sensor and the ejector, will the logic still work as is?  I understand the rest of it though. Thank you for the mock up!

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the kind of task that PLCs were designed for and shouldn't be too tricky to program. Whether or not you need anything else depends on the exact task and what hardware you already have.

Answer (score 0):

PLCs use a rather different programming paradigm from languages you may have used, and getting your head around "relay logic" may take a bit of head scratching, but you should have no problem implementing the logic you describe.

Essentially PLC logic attempts to emulate parallel logic by sampling the inputs and evaluating the outputs in a loop that executes continuously at a relatively high rate. They simulate timers and such like with control blocks. It's a familiar environment to those who have worked with logic relays, time delay relays and such like.

Some deviate from the pure relay logic in various ways.

The hardware is typically hardened for industrial use so that they're relatively immune to EMI and properly packaged to survive and be maintainable.